# Mask Input Value Date Format Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, masking

I want to mask my `input` value, basically I have an input field for credit card expiry date and want to mask it in format `mm/yy`, this is what I had tried :

**input-mask.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[formControlName][appInputMask]',
})
export class InputMaskDirective {

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    const trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').slice(0, 4);
    if (trimmed.length > 3) {
      return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(2)}`);
    }
  }
}
```

I got my expected output, but the problem is when using backspace on input field, it messed up, here is my demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-mask-34t827input?file=app/phone-mask.directive.ts), how to solve this? or is there any better approach on input mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The problems

1. HTMLInput element's maxlength should be 5 otherwise it won't allow a user to add 4 digits once you programmatically add a slash in it.
2. The same issue exist in `const trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').slice(0,4);` If it contains a slash, the slice should be end at 5 instead of 4.
3. In `return` statement

   ```
   return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(2)}`);
   ```

If the slash is added once, the `${trimmed.slice(2)` will return `/\d{1,2}`. So you need to avoid the slash and start from 3.

#### The solution

change max length to 5 from 4

```
 <input ... maxlength="5">
```

Now, *input-mask.directive.ts* need some changes

Change

```
const trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').slice(0,4);
```

to

```
const trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').slice(0, input.value.indexOf('/')==-1?4:5);
```

Because when you add `/`, the length will become 5.

> Don't use `.slice(0)` because it allows a user to paste 5 digits and when you add a slash, it'll become 6. So the date will look like `11/111` instead of `11/11`

Change

```
return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(2)}`);
```

to

```
return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(trimmed.indexOf('/')==-1?2:3)}`);
```

This is where your code getting messed up. If it contains a slash, then you should slice it from 3. Else slice it from 2.

final code of HostListener in input-mask directive

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  const input = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

  const trimmed = input.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').slice(0, input.value.indexOf('/')==-1?4:5);
  if (trimmed.length > 3) {
    return (input.value = `${trimmed.slice(0, 2)}/${trimmed.slice(trimmed.indexOf('/')==-1?2:3)}`);
  }
}
```

Working example : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-mask-34t827input-egk9hr)

Comment: I though special characters are not included, thats why I add `maxLength = 4`,

Comment: This doesn't filter months. For example, if you enter 8888 the output is 88/88

Comment: Please share a working example with the month filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngx-mask](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask#installing) will make your work easy by just giving pattern for date, card, etc.

`<input type='text' mask='99/99' >`

Here is [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-mask-34t827input-mpdufi)

Comment: good library, is there any solution using directive as my question ?

Comment: This doesn't filter months. For example, if you enter 8888 the output is 88/88

Answer (score 0):

use below code .
Create directive .ts file and add below code

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[formControlName][inputDateMask]',
})
export class InputMaskDirective {
    constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) { }

    @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
    onModelChange(event: any) {
        this.onInputChange(event, false);
    }

    @HostListener('keydown.backspace', ['$event'])
    keydownBackspace(event: any) {
        this.onInputChange(event.target.value, true);
    }

    onInputChange(event: any, backspace: any) {
        let newDate = '';
     
        let month: string = "";
        let day: string = "";
        let year: string = "";

        if (event)
            newDate = event.replace(/\D/g, '');

        if (backspace) {
            newDate = newDate.substring(0, newDate.length - 1);
        }
        if (newDate.length > 7) {

            if(newDate.match(/^[0-9]+$/) ? true : false)
            month = newDate.substring(0, 2);
            day = newDate.substring(2, 4);
            year = newDate.substring(4, 8);
            newDate = (`${month}/${day}/${year}`);

            this.ngControl?.valueAccessor?.writeValue(newDate);
        }
    }
}
```

then declare directive in app.module.ts file

```
declarations: [
 InputMaskDirective
],

exports: [
  InputMaskDirective
]
```

use directive like this

```
<input matInput placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" [maxlength]="10" inputDateMask formControlName="dateOfBirth" />
```

hope this help, thank you